# Define today's date as variable then pull data based on the variable

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to pull data from a database based on today's date.  I do not want to have to type in a date every time I run this.  I want this to be something I can run every day and base it on the current date.

I do not want to interfere with the data stored.  I am only trying to retrieve data based on today's date.  I think I should not have to go through making a variable for the date and should just be able to use curdate() or something?

Pseudo code:

```
declare variable as X (or whatever to represent the date)
then tell getdate() to populate X (determine what X is)
then 
select EntryDate, Name
from Table
where EntryDate = X    or where EntryDate is CurDate()   ????
```

so that it will print out something like this:

```
29Aug14  Suzie Que
29Aug14  Frank Man
29Aug14  Zebo Bebo
29Aug14  Tim Fields
29Aug14  Martha White
```

Comment: What is the type of your `EntryDate` field?  A datetime has resolution down to the millisecond, so you would need to query from midnight to 11:59:59 to see the whole day.

Comment: It's `SYSDATE`. You should be able to use `where EntryDate = SysDate()`, assuming EntryDate is actually a date column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `EntryDate` is a date field you can do something like this

```
select EntryDate, Name
from Table
where EntryDate = SYSDATE
```

I believe `SYSDATE` will have time too, so if you are comparing dates only do some formatting to get it to match

Answer (score 0):

I was using sysdate all wrong.  I ended up using something like this:

```
 select st.pers_ID, sh.request_date, sysdate    
 from pers_id st
 join ..... 
 where  
 sh.REQUEST_DATE between sysdate-1 and sysdate
```

This enabled me to always pull the last 24 hours.  Since this will be run at the same time every day (automatically and before business hours), it should be fine.  Thanks!
It printed something like this:

```
 ID     request_date    sysdate   
 81432  10-sep-14       11-sep-14  
 45796  11-sep-14       11-sep-14
```